# mysql max_allowed_packet doesn't return error when exceeded

Tags: mysql

I'd like know if this is a bug or what I am doing wrong here?

```
mysql> select @@max_allowed_packet
    -> ;
+----------------------+
| @@max_allowed_packet |
+----------------------+
|                 1024 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into Lookups values ('sasdfsadf12345654545=86672562768234jdfhasjkdfhaskldfhsadf','asdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdfasdfhasjkfhaskdfjaksdfhasjkdfhaksldfjhskajdfhaskdfhksjdfhkalsdfasdfasdfhjasdfhjkasdfhjkahsdf');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table Lookups;
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                       |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Lookups | CREATE TABLE `Lookups` (
  `name` text,
  `val` text
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
 +---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select version();
 +-----------+
 | version() |
 +-----------+
 | 5.0.77    |
 +-----------+
```

the insert statement is 1055 charactors long which should exceed the max_allowed_packet variable, yet it doesn't return any error

Comment: Check global value of this variable - SELECT @@global.max_allowed_packet. Maybe they are different.

Comment: Session and global max_allowed_packet are the same?